# Cannot open database "TurnAroundDB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\TurnAroundPool'

Tags: sql, database, wcf, iis, model-view-controller

I am runnig into the same problem that a few people run into but after reading a lot of threads I can not see where I am going wrong in order to fix the problem.
I have included my db user the the pool and the connection string in the web config. Any help would be appreciated.

> ```
> <value>Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial
> Catalog=TurnAroundDB; Persist Security Info=False; Integrated
> Security=false; Initial Catalog=TurnAroundDB</value>
> ```

[AppPool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sohC2.jpg)

[DB User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrX6K.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In DB (DB User window), go to `User Mapping` and check TurnAroundDB on the top side of the window. While there, you can assign the permissions you want for this user from the lower side of that window.

Comment: User mapping on the TrunAround has been set to public, datareader, datawriter and ddladmin. Server rolls are public and sysadmin. Status is Grant and Enabled